# Segmentation Fault on Recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, collatz

I want to count the number of recursivily call that has a number in the Collatz Sequence. But for such a bigger number for example 4565458458

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int f(int value){
    if(value==1) return 1;
    else if(value%2 == 0) return value/2;
    else return 3*value+1;
}

int g(int value){
   if(value == 0) return 0;
   if (f(value)==1) return 1;
   return 1 + g(f(value));
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int nSteps=0;
    istringstream iss(argv[1]);
    int;
    if(!(iss >> num).fail()){
        if(num < 0) cout << "0" << endl;
        else{
            nSteps = g(num);
            cout << "Result: " << nSteps << endl;
        } 
    }
    else{
        cout << "Incorrect line paramaters: ./g n" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: You are highly likely to get a stack overflow if you recurse enough

Comment: The program is incorrect, it would not compile, because of the following error `:24:17: error: ‘num’ was not declared in this scope`.

Comment: @Nemanja Trifunovic - the num-declaration was removed by an incorrect Edit.

Answer (score 4):

Your program will use a lot of stack-memory for large inputs.

In addition f should have the same input and output type (originally it had "unsigned long long" as input and int as output), or the result will be wrong.

I would advise you to first rewrite g without recursion, and if that works try to investigate how to get g to be efficient with tail-recursion (the current variant does probably not support it).

Using a debugger as others suggested is also good, especially if it crashes before calling 'g'.

Finally 'num<0' does not make sense for an unsigned 'num'.

Comment: Calculating `f(value)` twice is probably not helping the compiler spot the potential tail recursion optimisation